# Is "Perform all 32 bit float operations as 64 bit float" MORE or LESS compatible with .net?

Tags: ios, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin.iOS project properties, under "iOS Build" there's an option for: "Perform all 32 bit float operations as 64 bit float".

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/xamarin-ios-analysis#xia0005-float32rule) seems to say that using 32 bit "affects precision and, possibly, compatibility" in a bad way, so better use 64 bit precision.

But the popup on the text in visual studio (when hovering with the cursor over "Perform all 32 bit float operations as 64 bit float") says "using 64...is slightly incompatible with .net code."

So which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misread the statement in your first point. Microsoft doesn't say that using 32-bit is **bad**, so you need to use 64-bit. Just the opposite.

Basically, it is always preferable to use 64-bit float operations. They are enabled by default and according to the [Floating Point Operations in Xamarin.iOS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/floating-point):

> While this higher precision is closer to what developers expect from floating point operations in C# on the desktop, on mobile, the performance impact can be significant.

Let's see what the [Code Analysis tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/xamarin-ios-analysis) is:

> Xamarin.iOS analysis is a set of rules that check your project settings to help you determine if better/more optimized settings are available.

So, even though it is preferable to use 64-bit floats, this isn't always the best choice. When you run the Code analysis tool, it will scan your project to see if there is a better suited configuration for your solution (it depends on the project's flow).

Occasionally, the 64-bit floats may do you more harm than gain. In this case, the linter will warn you with `XIA0005: Float32Rule`, which will suggest that you **uncheck** the option, like the Microsoft's message says.

Comment: You might be right. So "enabling this option" in the link does _not_ mean checking the checkbox. That's quite confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that if something sounds confusing to you, you can always suggest an edit, especially if it's in the docs. You can suggest it either from the page itself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/xamarin-ios-analysis or through GitHub - there is a button at the end of the page.